# Getting linux system UUID which changes after reboot

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a linux system session id which is constant over the full runtime of the linux session (as long as uptime is increasing). After each reboot, it should be reset to another (random) value, probably formatted as a uuid.

I need this for logging in a global context, where I need to know if two logfiles come from the same session. Placing a stamp file in /tmp/ or another volatile folder could be an option but I want to avoid flooding such global folders. Using the system startup time is also not an option because the machine doesn't have an RTC battery and the time is reset after power loss. There will still be some milliseconds difference each time, but I don't want to risk collisions. Same thing with hashing the system start dmesg or parts of /proc or /sys.

I wonder if the kernel doesn't already provide such information over /proc or /sys?

Comment: Do you have the ability to access a broker to assign a UUID to the device as part of the `rc.local` (or other) startup script?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer The tool itself is running in user space. I would have to include such modifications to the install procedure

Comment: If your system is running `systemd`, you can just use the boot id for this purpose.

Comment: @larsks Sounds like what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I can't find information about how to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id
```

I found it while searching for systemd's "boot id". There was a DBus bug report referencing the file: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23679

Comment: Well, that saves me from finishing my answer :)

Comment: Well, that also saves you from getting the full reputation :-P but anyway, without your hint I wouldn't have found it